# How to code in Angular JS for resize function without using document and window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to change the below jQuery code in Angular JS without using Document and Window ? How to write the code without using Document.ready and window

Comment: What code? I think you might have forgotten to hit paste...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/afz6wwe7/1/ I have added the JS Fiddle. please check it.

Comment: how can i make a house without the foundation?

Comment: I have added the JS Fiddle please check it in comments.

Comment: I have code rest of the things in Angular JS but i am not able to do it for Document.ready function and resize function alone. Instead of document and window i am using div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS we have an option called calc
height: calc(100% - 75px);

This css tag solved the issue of resizing according to the screen.